# normalization of Repeating Groups

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, primary-key, normalization

My data consists of questions and answers. It also shows what the versionNr is of the answer and shows which persons changed which Answer. **Its possible that some questions have the same answer.**

```
questionID    Question      Answer       VersionNr    User            date
     1        Who is....?   W.H. Smith     1.0        ...@test.com   1/1/14          
                                           1.1        ...@test.com   3/8/14

     2        What is...?   3%             1.0        ...@test.com   1/2/14
```

RG = Repeating Group
Bold = Composite/Primary Key

0NF:
(**questionID**, question, AnswerID, answer,RG{versionNr, user, date}

1NF:
(**questionID**, question, AnswerID, answer)
(questionID, **AnswerID**, **VersionNr**, user, date)

2NF/3NF:
Q(**questionID**, question, AnswerID)
Ans(**AnswerID**, answer)
Version(questionID, **AnswerID**, **VersionNr**, user, date)

My question is whether I should remove questionID from Version, because the versionNr, date and User gives information about the Answer and Not the question.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that two questions might have the same answer? If you mean that this is, for example, a math quiz, and you might have two questions that both have the answer "4", I'd say this is irrelevant. You wouldn't want both questions to point to the same answer record, because what if someone realizes that one of these answers is a mistake and should be "3"? Well, maybe your answer records are immutable because if there's a change, you create a new version. But looking for coincidental duplicates so, what, you can save creating a record?, isn't normally a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, I believe you can do the following to achieve a working 3NF schema.

Q(**questionID**, question)

Ans(**AnswerID**,answer,*QuestionID*)

Version(**VersionNr**,***AnswerID***,**User**,date)

(Italics are foreign keys)

So, the primary key of version is triple {VersionNr,AnswerID,User). Please explain if something is not correct with my solution.

So, to sum up, no, you don't need to have questionID inside version, since you can find it with joins.

**UPDATE**

I think I understand your problem and I believe the correct solution is the following.

Q(**questionID**,question)

Ans(**AnswerID**,answer)

Version(***QuestionID***,***AnswerID***,VersionNr,user,date)

Actually, your relationship between answers and question is many to many, since many answers are connected to many questions. So, you can use Version as the intermediate table to construct this many to many relationship.

Additionally, you can add the version number, the user and the date in that intermediate table, to have all the necessary information.

Comment: I think the primary key would simply be (answerID, versionNr). If someone updates the answer, there should be a new versionNr. If that's not true, tacking on "user" doesn't necessarily help. What if user A enters an answer, user B changes it, and then user A changes it again? Unless there's some guarantee that each user can only change an answer once, including user in the key doesn't help make it unique.

Comment: I haven't understood if he wants to be able to find the latest answers of each user, or the latest answer in general. I believe he wants to be able to find each user's latest answer. So, only VersionNr and AnswerID aren't enough, since two users that answer the same question in the same way (and with the same version) would have identical primary keys in version table.

Comment: Oh, could be. I was thinking that the users are updating what is considered the "right answer". It could be that each user is updating is own answer. Actually that might make more sense. Like if this is a quiz, I'm not sure if the users are the teachers or the students.

Answer (score 0):

If there can be many version records for one answer record, then yes, QuestionID should not be in Version, as it is redundant data: You can always tell the QuestionID of a Version by looking up the Answer record.

That said, it's not clear to me what you're trying to model. When you say that a user can change an answer, do you mean that this is a quiz and users can change what the "right answer" is? Or do you mean that they can change the answer they gave to a quiz or survey?

But if there are many Version records for one Answer, than you are not recording what the answer was at each step, you are just recording who made the change. Maybe that's all you need to know for your purposes. But if the idea is that you want to record what the answer was for each version, then Answer and Version should be a combined into a single table. In that case you need questionID in the Answer/Version record because otherwise you have no way to know which question any answer other than the latest is for.

If the idea is that there is just one Answer record for each Question, and then many versions, then Question and Answer should be combined into a single record. Well, you say that several questions can share the same answer. As I asked in a comment, what does this mean? Are you talking about answers that are the same by coincidence, like on question is "How much is 2+2?" and another is "What is the square root of 16?" and both answers happen to be 4? Or do you mean that they are really the same answer in the sense that if the answer to one question changed, the answer to the other would logically and inevitably have to change to the same thing? Like, "Who is the current vice president of the United States?" and "If the president of the United States died, who would become president?"

I'd think the logical schema would be this:

```
Question (questionID, question_text)
Answer (answerID, questionID, version_number, answer_text, user, change_date)
```

Then the current answer is

```
select answer_text
from answer
where questionID=@qid
  and version_number=(select max(version_number) from answer
    where questionID=@qid)
```

This requires no redundant data.

An obvious denormalization for performance and simplicity would be to put the answerID of the current answer in the Question record.

Comment: My data can be seen as FAQ. A lot of questions in my data have the same answer. Its true that I dont want to save the older versions of the Answers. Shouldnt the answerID stay in Question? Because the questions only have 1 answer, and the answer can be associate with multiple questions . Which means its a (1:N) relationship between answer and question.

Comment: I don't understand how 2 questions can share an answer. You say this is a FAQ? So like there could be multiple questions that are really the same question just worded differently? Like one person asks, say, "How can I build a moon rocket?", and you post an answer, and then someone else asks, "How can I travel to the moon?", and you say, oh, that's the same as that other question, and point both to the same answer? If that's the case, and if you also have multiple versions of an answer, then it's not 1:M, it's M:N: each question has multiple answers, each answer has multiple questions.